# Using icons with MIT licensing on the website

Tags: licensing

On the website, I use these SVG icons embedded in HTML https://feathericons.com/. They are under the MIT license. Should I mark the author somehow? How should I do it? Is it enough if I add something like this in HTML:

```
<!-- Svg icons by https://feathericons.com/ -->
<!doctype html>
...
```

EDIT: I need to write something like this: https://github.com/feathericons/feather/blob/master/LICENSE? If so, where should I write it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok it is not a solution but debate; What you have done so far is all good in its sense but it is not in direct view of person receiving the content aka user.

A good approach would be to place the licencing information in about us or term of use/EULA section if you go down this path. These very sections of website list and detail what is what and how it impacts the user.
Make a sub heading called third party licences and list all you need to list in that section. Make the primary link public on all pages and you are good to go.
Some examples below.

[image]

[image]

Side note, if I am crafting large enough application I would always use this keeping everything tidy up in one place. I was originally motivated to adopt this approach seeing how Microsoft and other legacy companies turned page towards Open source and how they reflected the library information. Obviously they had brains who would have thought it over so there is merit by virtue.

Comment: Ok, great, I hadn't thought of that. However, is this required or is my idea from the question not legal?

Comment: My site is small, so can I include the contents of the MIT licence in the HTML comment? Will this be legal?

Comment: Obviously it depends on the scale of the application. There is no hard and fast rule as to what and where to include, there are good practices. HTML comments are envisioned for HTML related concerns not legal notices. Secondly HTML it self is an aggregation of various codes which may be in place resources or external resources aka over the network or linking. Two very different things legally speaking. Licence goes wherever the source is of given library or goes where the attribution is made as in case of disclaimer or term of use or about us.

Comment: If you have SPA or couple of pages of MPA then placing reference to short licence head <!-- Svg icons MIT License at https://feathericons.com/ --> is suffice enough but point to actual License text in url e.g. have you ever seen how they add license heads on css files? follow that routine example below

Comment: Bootstrap example 
/*!
 * Bootstrap v3.4.1 (https://getbootstrap.com/)
 * Copyright 2011-2019 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 *//*! normalize.css v3.0.3 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */ see they have added additional normalise css to the mix as well. just copy this format and move it to HTML code just before using the library or very first thing in the HTML it self. It is would be perfectly fine.  Key word using License head not the whole license.